# Identify Objects from captured image

Tags: objective-c, ios, image

In my app, i need to implement image recognition techniques like Google goggles  functionality. I need to capture one object [like book or place etc] via cam. i need to show the real content from Google as well as Google links  . Is it possible in ios?If YES please let me known what are all the SDK available and how to achieve? Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these APIs, http://www.moodstocks.com/ or http://intopii.com/en/home or https://www.iqengines.com/ or try [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348040/iphone-and-opencv)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537977/image-recognition-library-api-for-iphone-code)