# Image Recognition iPhone facing issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-recognition

I have used the following help [Image recognition library/API for iPhone code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537977/image-recognition-library-api-for-iphone-code) to use an API - http://www.moodstocks.com/ to create an image recognition app. Now my questions are:

1> I want to play a video when the user scans the image successfully in the landscape. But it does not seem to support landscape anyhow.

2> It could be because i am not pushing another controller, But adding another controller's view into

```
self.view
```

This is chiefly because it crashes when i try to add another controller modally or via push.

3> The sample code can be downloaded here - https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-iphone-demo-app

4> I received an email stating i have done 66/1000 scans. Does that imply that i will have just 1000 scans total?

Comment: ScarletWitch: you can find answers to your questions on the official [help center](http://help.moodstocks.com/customer/portal/questions/1282894-orientation-issues-please-help-). Feel free to continue the discussion right there and provide more details!

Comment: Ok thanks. I added on this platform to get more ideas. Thanks for your help btw.